# justify-content not working properly on buttons

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, flexbox

I have 3 buttons nested within a parent container.  The parent container has `display:inline-flex`, but the `justify-content: space-between` property isn't working.  The buttons have a `max-width` defined (since `justify-content` can only work when there's empty space available).  At this point, when I try different values for `justify-content` (`space-between`, `space-around`, `center`, etc) the grouping of buttons is moved around, but the individual buttons never separate.  I've tinkered with this for a while, and read through a bunch of StackOverflow answers, but nothing has worked so far.  Any help is appreciated!  [I have a codepen for testing things out.](https://codepen.io/dillweed5446/pen/jOGmEmP)  It's a simplified version of my angular code.

Just to fully document my issue here is the relevant code from production and a screenshot:

```css
.loop-container {
  display: inline-flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
}

button {
  height: 30px
  flex: 1
}

.cancel {
  background-color: red
}

.home {
  background-color: blue
}

.small {
  max-width: 75px
}

.large {
  max-width: 140px
  }
```

```html
<ng-container class="button-container">
  <div class='loop-container'>
    <button class='cancel small'>Cancel</button>
    <button class='home small'>Home</button>
    <button class='cancel large'>Cancel Machine</button>
  </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: `flex: 1` on the buttons applies `flex-grow: 1`, telling each item to consume all available space. Hence, the `justify-content` property on the parent won't work, as there's no free space available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer: Don't use `display: inline-flex`, but `display: flex` on the flex container. That way the flex container will be 100% wide by default.

Also, you wrote about `justify-content: space-between`  not working, but in your code you have `justify-content: center`  (?). I changed that to `space-between` in my snippet to show the effect.

```css
.loop-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 30px flex: 1
}

.cancel {
  background-color: red
}

.home {
  background-color: blue
}

.small {
  max-width: 75px
}

.large {
  max-width: 140px
}
```

```html
<ng-container class="button-container">
  <div class='loop-container'>
    <button class='cancel small'>Cancel</button>
    <button class='home small'>Home</button>
    <button class='cancel large'>Cancel Machine</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

You might also want to try `space-around`, which will leave some space at the far right and left too:

```css
.loop-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 30px flex: 1
}

.cancel {
  background-color: red
}

.home {
  background-color: blue
}

.small {
  max-width: 75px
}

.large {
  max-width: 140px
}
```

```html
<ng-container class="button-container">
  <div class='loop-container'>
    <button class='cancel small'>Cancel</button>
    <button class='home small'>Home</button>
    <button class='cancel large'>Cancel Machine</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I did that before, but the buttons weren't lining up.  It also didn't solve the problem.  inline-flex should still allow me to use flex properties, but keep the buttons inline.  Thanks though!

Comment: please note the edit to my answer

Comment: Yes, I had the `justify-content: center` as a temporary placeholder in production since it looked better than the other options.  I changed display to flex, but it only stacked the buttons one on top of the other, and they need to be inline.  Space-around would be fine too, but again, it is only moving the buttons around together, and not spacing them apart.

Comment: There must be something else happening in production for me because I see in you example that it does what it should.  I'm marking this correct.  Just need to figure out what other styles are throwing off my production code.  Thanks @Johannes!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have a gap between all the buttons then you'll have to add the margin, Justify content doesn't add a space between elements, it just moves  the content based on your property values.

```css
.loop-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

.home {
  background-color: blue;
}

.small {
  max-width: 75px;
}

.large {
  max-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<ng-container class="button-container">
  <div class='loop-container'>
    <button class='cancel small'>Cancel</button>
    <button class='home small'>Home</button>
    <button class='cancel large'>Cancel Machine</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I don't want to add margin because this needs to be flexible on different screens.  It's possible to space the elements using flex and `justify-content: space-between` as I've done it plenty of times previously.  Not sure why it isn't working in this instance.  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: Because you're using inline-flex, inline-flex won't leave any expending space for inner content. Even in your ref. the link you can see in the demo creator using `display: flex;` then the inner content will be justified with space left. if in that demo you'll set `display: inline-flex` you'll see the same thing that you have in your demo.

Comment: When I use `display: flex` the buttons are no longer inline.  `justify-content` still isn't working in that case either.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by inline buttons, but if you're looking for buttons to show on the left when you use display flex then you use `justify-content: flex-start;`
`justify-content: center;` will justify all the content to the center. I think you're just confused with the use of justify-content.

Comment: inline === same row.

Comment: As you update your original snippet with display: flex and I can see all three buttons are in the same row. Not sure where you don't see them in the same row. If you're worrying about the small screen sizes where buttons wrap below then you need to set the `flex-wrap: nowrap;`
you also wanna set `white-space: nowrap;` in buttons as well to avoid wrap in button texts.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that it's working in this context, but it still isn't working in production for some reason.  Trying to figure out why that is now.  I've already accepted Johannes answer.  Also, `flex-wrap: nowrap` is the default.